# International phone number input for Polymer

Tags: javascript, html, formatting, polymer

I need an input element using webcomponents that allows you to decide which country you would like, and then a phone number, which should be formatted accordingly.
[Gold phone input](https://www.webcomponents.org/element/PolymerElements/gold-phone-input/elements/gold-phone-input) doesn't have a country selection, and -- even worse -- doesn't have pre-set for phone numbers.
I thought about using [paper-countries](https://github.com/bluewatertracks/paper-countries) along with gold-phone-number, but it doesn't come with area codes.

The only real option is https://github.com/jackocnr/intl-tel-input, but I *really* don't want to use Jquery JUST for this.

Are these really my only options?

Comment: I had the same issue before, I use firebase database, the firebase has phone sign up option if you needed, you may check up firebase auth. Check it from https://jobijoy.com, Firebase have a good phone sign up. check this link for more info:https://github.com/firebase/firebaseui-web

Comment: That is the kind of element I am after. However, I am not using Firebase and am not willing to add huge amounts of code to my app just for an input field -- hence me looking for a polymer solution. There is an element taht looks totally decent, but it's a JQuery plugin -- same problem there.

Comment: the `intl-tel-input` library is now independent of jQuery, which should make it easier to implement